# Flutter app stuck at installing with white screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

My flutter app is always getting stuck in installing when I run on my device Lenovo L18021, app is launched with the white screen and it is not moving past that, I am not running a custom app, I am just running the demo app comes as default, I tried changing package name of the app and used flutter clean multiple times, I used File->Invalidate cache and Restart option multiple times in android studio, I found that I am receiving an untrusted app message in the logcat, I do not know if that is the issue, I also increased the buffer size on my device, and the app is launching fine in the web and from my android studio the native android apps are launching on that device correctly, only the flutter apps are not launching, that too while launching from the android studio only. If I opened the installed app in my phone later the app is running correctly, I even did a factory reset on my device then tried to run the app from android studio, still it is not working, "flutter doctor -v" is not showing any errors, I have been stuck with this issue for the past two weeks kindly help me to resolve this issue ?

My screenshots

launch screen

[image: While lauching]

Flutter doctor -v
[image: doctor]

Logcat
[image]

Device screenshot
[image]

Comment: try `flutter run -v --enable-software-rendering` from the terminal window, does it change anything?

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` ? Also what about other platoforms ? Does it run on iOS sims ?

Comment: @pskink "flutter run -v --enable-software-rendering" command correctly launches the app on the device, the issue happens only when "Run" button is used to launch the app, any suggestions ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d Tried 'flutter clean' multiple times and also tried 'Invalidate cache and Restart' option in android studio multiple times. App launches in web platform and I think it will also launch in iOS(I am using windows so noway for me to test in IOS), the problem happens only in my android phone, in the emulator also it is working fine.

Comment: so you have to add `--enable-software-rendering` in android studio run configuration

Comment: @pskink I have added that still it is not working, any other suggestions?

Comment: then run `flutter run` from the terminal window, this is how i do all the time

Comment: @pskink yes, I will do that from now onwards, Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Didn’t you accidentally create two different MainActivity files, with different project name. If so delete one.

android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/YOUR_PROJECT/MainActivity.kt